# Using a =IF(OR formula when I want a partial match

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I've got the following formula, but it does not work as when I add the *California* around the name it just fails so it just tells me that everything is UK. How can I fix this?

```
=IF(OR(N10776="*California*",N10776="*San Francisco*",N10776="*New York*"),"USA","UK")
```

Comment: `=` doesn't support wild cards.  Use `Find` or `Search`

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```
=IF(OR(IFERROR(SEARCH("California",N10776)>0,FALSE),IFERROR(SEARCH("San Francisco",N10776)>0, FALSE),IFERROR(SEARCH("New York",N10776)>0,FALSE)),"USA","UK")
```

Answer (score 1):

Try below formula.

```
=IF(OR(ISNUMBER(SEARCH({"California","San Francisco","New York"},A1))),"USA","UK")
```

May need array entry `CTRL`+`SHIFT`+`ENTER` for older versions of Excel.

[image]